# Как подключить сдвиговые регистры 74hc595 и 74hc165 по 4 пинам к attiny85

Tags: arduino

Взял клавиатуру qwerty из старого телефона. Там идет матрица кнопок 8x8. Пытаюсь её подключить через данные сдвиговые регистры к attiny85 в которой 2-а пина к usb. Остальные 4 пина для регистров. Можно ли подключить их по 4 пинам и как?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.